# external command fails td-agent

Tags: fluentd, td-agent

This bash command "`etcdctl get system config/log/timestamp`" returns time type either UTC or System. Now i want to use this to convert time to same format. How can i do that?

I tried this but it failed td-agent running.

```
<source>
  @type exec
  command etcdctl get system config/log/timestamp
  <parse>
    keys timeType
  </parse>
</source>
```

Now i want to use that timeType to convert my time from given log to that timeType

```
{"host":"sp-1","level":"INFO","log":{"classname":"common.server.hacluster.CSFHATopologyChangeHandlerMBean:93","message":"Finished processing CSF HA 'become standby' message.","stacktrace":"","threadname":"RMI TCP Connection(1784)-192.168.20.11"},"process":"becomeStandby","service":"SP","time":"2020-03-19T10:15:36.514Z","timezone":"America/Toronto","type":"log","system":"SP_IG_20_3_R1_I2002","systemid":"SP_IG_20_3_R1_I2002"}
```

This is where i want to use that $timeType

```
<filter com.logging.tmplog>
  @type record_modifier
  <record>
  type log
  time ${record["time"]}.$timeType   ## It's not working
  arun ${tag}
  </record>
</filter>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as a [tag:ruby] question?

Comment: I did it because fluentd has plugins in ruby. So may be the solution can be ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by using record-modifier's prepare_value

`<filter com.logging.tmplog>
   @type record_modifier
   prepare_value @timeType =``etcdctl get system config/log/timestamp`.strip

`<record>
    timeType ${@timeType}
    time ${if @timeType == 'UTC' then Time.at(time).utc.strftime('%FT%T') else Time.at(time).to_s; end} 
   </record>
 </filter>`